# OAuth2 - Benefits for using Grant-Type:Password for machine-to-machine web-service calls

Tags: oauth2

I'm using a 3rd party service developed by the [Experian](https://developer.experian.com/) Credit Bureau. Looking at their [documentation](https://developer.experian.com/get-started), they are using OAuth2 & are expecting `Grant_type: password` in order for external developers to obtain an `access_token`. So, the developer must pass their username/password/client id & client secret (the last 2 of which you create and retrieve via the developer portal)

To get the `access_token` you would call the following endpoint;

```
curl -X POST https://sandbox-us-api.experian.com/oauth2/v1/token \
  -H 'Accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Content-type: application/json' \
  -H 'Grant_type: password' \
  -d '{"username": "<USERNAME>","password": "<PASSWORD>","client_id": "<CLIENT_ID>","client_secret": "<CLIENT_SECRET>"}'
```

Everything works fine and I've no problem obtaining the access token *however* I don't understand how this is any more secure than simply passing a username/password (which oauth2 was designed to avoid); These services are normally *machine-to-machine* invoked so you will need to have the credentials stored on the system calling their services so if a bad actor was to steal these then they can obtain the client_id & client_secret by simply logging into the developer portal.

They are using Okta who says that password grants should only ever be used for [trusted internal apps](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/06/29/what-is-the-oauth2-password-grant) but this isn't the use-case for these services - we are *not* internal nor trusted.

Alternatively, I could architect so that the calling machine only works with the `access_token` and `refresh_token` however that means you need to re-authenticate when the `refresh_token` expires (24 hours) which in my case the service is only invoked once per week - this means I would have to reset the `access_token` manually each week.

What am I missing that makes this approach more secure than a simple username/password exchange?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in the section 4.3 of the RFC6749 ([here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3))

> The resource owner password credentials grant type is suitable in
> cases where the resource owner has a trust relationship with the
> client, such as the device operating system or a highly privileged
> application. The authorization server should take special care when
> enabling this grant type and only allow it when other flows are not
> viable.
>
> It is also used to migrate existing clients using direct
> authentication schemes such as HTTP Basic or Digest authentication to
> OAuth by converting the stored credentials to an access token

In sum, you can use it if you have a strong trust relationship with the client application OR to "update" legacy applications in such a way as to avoid the use of authorization methods in the original HTTP spec and to benefit from stuff like scopes, expirations that you cannot guarantee with a simple `basic auth`

So to answer your question: No, you are missing nothing, the `Grant-Type` is not suitable for modern applications.